# Running jQuery functions one by one to execute CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxj4ebLc/). I would like to achieve 'one page full screen' type of webpage. I have two sections; display one at a time by `display:block/none;`each section contains content; `.content1, .content2` respectively; content `div` works as a button to fire another section. You can also see a fixed header.

Section `.intro` contains `.content1`, section `.archive` contains `.content2`.

Now, I would like to build following chain of events on click: (i) `.content1` fades out, (ii) `.intro` gets `display:none`, `.archive` gains `display:block`, (iii) `.content2`fades in.

The other way around, respectively, on click on `.content2`: (i) `.content2` fades out, (ii) `.archive` gets `display:none`, `.intro` gains `display:block`, (iii) `.content1`fades in.

I have some experience with CSS, so I made and checked css transitions for fade in, fade out effects. Up to this point, everything is clear for me.

My problem is, however, I do not know how to build the chains of events. I have googled a lot of similar questions and tried some solutions, but had no luck. I have very little experience with JavaScript, so there might be some obvious mistakes in how I tried to implement the solutions.

I do not attach script in my fiddle; I would like to ask if you could point me in the right direction rather than fix my code, because, you see, I am not sure which solution I should show--so far they all look equally hopeless for me.

Should I go with JavaScript? JQuery? Pure CSS? Could you sketch / write some code how you would handle the problem?

Could you review the idea of displayed/hidden sections for the effect I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Currently I think this question is too broad. Can you narrow it down to a specific programming question?

Comment: @TylerH I've updated [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxj4ebLc/4/). I've managed to fire steps (i) and (ii) from my original question, but still couldn't implement (iii). I've tried simple .addClass('active') to .archive, but the 'fade in' css transformation (scale from 0.7 -> 1) does not play. I double checked if the whole css transition is right, and it is, I just couldn't pull the effect - the element displays in scale 1 from the get go.

Could you help me write a callback or something that would play the whole transition (to the existing function, because (i)-(iii) should play at 1 click)?

Comment: @TylerH I've updated [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxj4ebLc/6/) again. It seems that the (i)-(iii) steps work just fine now, but the code is far from being elegant. Could you review my work and send a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` should be fine:

```
 $(".toarchive").click(function(){
    $('.intro').fadeOut();
    $(".intro").removeClass("active");
    $(".intro").css("display", "none");
    $(".archive").fadeIn();
    $(".archive").css("display", "block");
    $(".archive").addClass("active");
});
```

However, if you're worried about the wait time between fades, you can use `setTimeout`:

```
$(".toarchive").click(function(){
    $('.intro').fadeOut();
    $(".intro").removeClass("active");
    $(".intro").css("display", "none");
    setTimeout(testThis, 1000);
}); 

function testThis(){
    $(".archive").fadeIn();
    $(".archive").css("display", "block");
    $(".archive").addClass("active");
}
```

[Try here](https://jsfiddle.net/nxj4ebLc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it automaticallys does what you want and it's cleaner.

Just put class show at page container you want to show first then clicking next will loop through pages.

Or you could set page number yourself and it will show that page.

**http://jsfiddle.net/ot2gyxme/**

```
var pages = $('.full'),
    len = pages.length,
    showing = pages.index($('.full.show'));

$('.next').click(function(){
    pages.stop().eq(showing).fadeOut(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            showing = ++showing % len; //set this number to show x page
            pages.eq(showing).fadeIn();
        },1000); //time logo remains visible in ms.
    });

});
```